# Dude into an Android App which RecycleView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hi I was developing an Android App which show a RecycleView of "Recetas", based on the time and ingredients which you have.

My problem is that the data is on an SQLite database, and I don't know how to charge the content of the Receta class, specifically the name and description of it.

Another problem is that my chackBox I don't know why but don't get Selected when you click on it,
although I put the "setEnable" and "clickable" attributes to true.

Here it's the code

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView scroll_resul;
    private ArrayList<Receta>listaRecetas;
    private AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin;
    private String categoriaSelected;
    private AdapterReceta adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        scroll_resul = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        scroll_resul.setLayoutManager (layoutManager);

        categoriaSelected = "";

        admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this);

        for (int i=0; i<scroll_resul.getChildCount(); i++){


            View vista = scroll_resul.getChildAt(i);
            final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) vista;
            if(check.getTag() != null && vista.getTag().toString().equals("opcion")) {

                check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked) {
                            if (!(categoriaSelected.isEmpty())) {
                                categoriaSelected = categoriaSelected + ", " + check.getText().toString() + "'";
                            } else {
                                categoriaSelected = "'" + check.getText().toString() + "'";
                            }
                        } else {

                            categoriaSelected = categoriaSelected.replace(check.getText().toString(),
                                    "");

                        }
                        //Esto se lanza siempre
                        InstanciarCategoria(categoriaSelected);
                    }
                });
            }
        }


    }

    private List<Receta> getListRecetas(String categoria, Integer tiempo) {

        listaRecetas = new ArrayList<Receta>();
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase database = admin.getReadableDatabase();
        if (tiempo != null) {
            Cursor fila = database.rawQuery("select descripcion, categoria, ingredientes from recetas where categoria in (" + categoria + ") and tiempo <=" + tiempo + ";", null);

            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    listaRecetas.add(new Receta(fila.getString(0), fila.getString(2)));
                } while (fila.moveToFirst());
                database.close();
            }

        }else{
            Cursor fila = database.rawQuery("select descripcion, categoria, ingredientes from recetas where categoria in (" + categoria + ";", null);

            if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    listaRecetas.add(new Receta(fila.getString(0), fila.getString(2)));
                } while (fila.moveToFirst());
                database.close();
            }
        }
        return listaRecetas;
    }

    public void InstanciarCategoria(String categoria){

            adapter = new AdapterReceta(getListRecetas(categoria, null), this);
            scroll_resul.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

AdaterReceta.class

```
public class AdapterReceta extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterReceta.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private List<Receta> localDataSet;

/**
 * Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
 * (custom ViewHolder).
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView txtTitulo;
    private final TextView txtDescripcion;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View

        txtTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
        txtDescripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
    }

    public TextView gettxtTitulo() {
        return txtTitulo;
    }

    public TextView getTxtDescripcion() {
        return txtDescripcion;
    }
}

    /**
     * Initialize the dataset of the Adapter.
     *
     * @param dataSet String[] containing the data to populate views to be used
     * by RecyclerView.
     */
    public AdapterReceta(List<Receta> dataSet, Context context) {
        this.localDataSet = dataSet;
        this.context=context;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view, which defines the UI of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_receta, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // Get element from your dataset at this position and replace the
        // contents of the view with that element
        viewHolder.gettxtTitulo().setText(localDataSet.get(position).getNombre());
        viewHolder.getTxtDescripcion().setText(localDataSet.get(position).getDescripcion());
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return localDataSet.size();
    }
}
```

AdminSQLiteHelper.class

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Recetas.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "recetas";

    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
       @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL("create table  " +TABLE_NAME+ " ( codigo integer primary key autoincrement, categoria text, descripcion text, tiempo int, ingredientes text)");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (0, 'Pasta', 'Pasta con brócoli y nueces', 30, 'macarrones, brocoli, nueces')");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (1, 'Pasta', 'Pasta con verduras al estilo caponata siciliana', 40, '400 gr de pasta, la que prefieras, 2 berenjenas, 1 cebolla, 400 gr de tomate' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (2, 'Pasta', 'Tortellinis de pasta fresca casera rellenos con carrilleras de cerdo en salsa', 30, '160 gr de harina de trigo, 4 huevos L,Pimienta negra recién molida y sal, queso parmesano rallado')");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (3, 'Pasta', 'Spaghetti a la boloñesa', 25, '400 gr de spaghetti,300 gr de carne picada, 1 zanahoria, 1 cebolla, 100 ml de vino blanco ')");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (4, 'Arroz', 'macarrones con brócoli y nueces', 30, 'macarrones, brocoli,' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (5, 'Arroz', 'Arroz con lomo ibérico', 30, 'Pimiento rojo, 1 pequeño, Pimiento verde, 1 pequeño, 1 diente de ajo, tomate frito, lomo ibérico' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (6, 'Arroz', 'Arroz frito rápido', 30, 'arroz, aceite, agua, sal, zanahoria, puerro, salsa de soja' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (7, 'Arroz', 'Arroz redondo', 30, 'arroz, caldo, tomate, cebolla , ajo, tabasco, cilantro' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (8, 'Arroz', 'Arroz cantonés', 40, 'Arroz basmati, agua, filete de ternera, zanahoria, guisantes' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (9, 'Huevos', 'Huevos rancheros', 45, '8 ud de Tortillas de maíz, 8 huevos, tomate maduros, 2 cebollas, carne picada, pimiento rojo' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (10,'Huevos', 'Huevos revueltos con espárragos trigueros y calabacín', 50, 'calabacín, espárragos verdes trigueros, aceite, queso rallado, cebollino' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (11,'Huevos', 'Tortilla de patatas', 25, '4 patatas, 6 huevos, aceite y sal' )");
           db.execSQL("insert into recetas (codigo, categoria, descripcion, tiempo, ingredientes) values (12,'Huevos', 'Huevos fritos con pisto manchego', 15, '4 huevos,  2 cebollas, 2 tomates maduros, pimienta' )");


       }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS%s", TABLE_NAME));
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Receta.class

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
public class Receta {

    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;

    public Receta(String nombre, String descripcion){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.descripcion=descripcion;

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Receta{" +
                "nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                ", descripcion='" + descripcion + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

I hope you can guess where the problem is, and if is like this take thanks for advance!
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: have you checked my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see in your code is that `Select` you are missing a parenthesis

```
Cursor fila = database.rawQuery("select descripcion, categoria, ingredientes from recetas where categoria in (" + categoria + ");", null);
```

Other one is you have a global variable for your `AdminSQLiteOpenHelper` and you initialise it in the `onCreate()` why you need to do it again in the `private List<Receta> getListRecetas(...)`? You can use the `this.admin` one.

Also, I don't get this

```
public void InstanciarCategoria(String categoria){
    adapter = new AdapterReceta(getListRecetas(categoria, null), this);
    scroll_resul.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

What are you trying to do here? I mean, for each "categoría" you create a new `AdapterReceta`?
Could you explain better what is your desired output? You want only one list or more? And what are you doing with CheckBox?

If you want to update your `RecyclerView` you do not have to create it again and set it, you can do it from start and then on every change you do something like :

```
adapter.setRecetas(PASS_THE_NEW_LIST_OF_RECETAS)
```

and inside the `AdapterReceta` you create a method like this :

```
public void setRecetas(yourList) {
  localDataSet.clear();
  localDataSet.addAll(yourList);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And doing this it will update the list for you.